# get a document from firestore with a required phone number

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, fetch

I have a collection of users in have created docs names as per their UID and each doc has a field "phoneNumber" , I want to get a **SINGLE Document**
In numberArray i have some selected numbers to be searched

```dart
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: number.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => FutureBuilder(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Users")
            .where('phone', isEqualTo: number[index])
            .get(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
            return ListTile();
          else return Container();
```

Comment: what is the error arising?

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your Firestore document